# Mock interface based on type object

Tags: c#, mocking

I want to mock some interfaces based on type object. I need this to call constructor via reflection. It will look like that:

```
        var type = typeof (T);
        var constructors = type.GetConstructors();
        var constructor = constructors.First();
        var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
        var objects = new object[parameters.Count()];
        //TODO create mock parameters and add to aobject array
        constructor.Invoke(objects);
```

Is it possible to achieve sth like that? Does any mock framework give finctionality for this? Or maybe it can be done using BCL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bump was partially right, but this what I want to get is a mock cretated via reflection and solution for this will look like that:

```
public static object DynamicMock(Type type)
{
   var mock = typeof(Mock<>).MakeGenericType(type).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[] { });
   return mock.GetType().GetProperties().Single(f => f.Name == "Object" && f.PropertyType == type).GetValue(mock, new object[] {});
}
```